# How to implement a finished coded html/css page into CMS

Tags: javascript, html, css, content-management-system

I want to implement a live website (its already coded & released), coded with HTML & CSS (with some CSS3 effects), the website is this: www.style-euclides.pt

**What I want to do?**

Add new images to gallery, change/update image slider images & change "About" text/info

**What I want to know?**

Its there a simple CMS to implement on this page, one that a rookie developer could understand and implement without many changes?

Any tip or help will be appreciated...

Comment: you already choose your CMS plataform? eg: Wordpress, Drupal, Joomla?

Comment: I haven't, I need suggestions, I saw some pro's & cons but its hard to figure out my needs about this website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, you will need to decide on what CMS platform you would like to use and then create a theme that outputs the markup and CSS that you are using currently, leveraging the CMS capabilities for the content.

This question is very vague, but once you select a CMS, it shouldn't be too difficult to create a template that outputs your markup. You could start by simply finding the page that generates the 'home' page in the CMS, and paste in all your HTML while maintaining the functions that allow the CMS to work.

Once you have a working site that is rendered by the CMS, you would need to update your site to utilize the CMS capabilities. For example, if you wanted to separate each section on the site into 'pages' in the CMS, you would create these 'pages' in the CMS, and then update your homepage template to pull in content from each of those pages instead of just outputting raw hand-coded HTML.

From there, you would want to use whatever functionality you can from the CMS to do the heavy lifting. The CMS you choose should be able to take a batch of images, upload them to the server, associate them as a gallery together and allow you to insert a gallery into a page, but how you do this will depend on which CMS you choose.

Comment: The problem I don't know which one would fit the needs I have for this website. I want something lightweight & user-friedly

Comment: You have to do your own research. There are pros and cons for each solution.

Comment: Basically, I can put "any" CMS, can be Joomla, or Wordpress, without many problems of adaptation? I also have a concern about responsive-ness